# PHP Вопрос тестовый: При каких значениях $a и $b, $res будет true?

Tags: php, логика

Добрый день! Есть следующая задача
Дано выражение:

```
$res = ($a==true && $b==false && $a==$b);
```

При каких значениях `$a` и `$b`, `$res` будет true?

Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При следующем раскладе;

Когда `$a` принимает строку любую кроме строки ноль (`$a='0';`) и пустой строки (`$a='';`)

А `$b = 0`; Именно нулю , потому что В PHP есть понятие приоритетов,И когда число сравнивается со строкой `(0 == 'abc')`, то приоритет у числа больше и строка приводится к числу `0` чтоб суметь сравнить. Вот одна из причин почему есть этот оператор `===`;.

```
<?php
    $a = 'любая строка кроме пустой и нуля';
    $b = 0;
    $res = ($a==true && $b==false && $a==$b);
    var_dump($res);
?>
```

На пальцах перевожу выражение:

1) `$a == true` равно `'abc' == true` (`$а` это строка и оно истинно) `true == true = true`

2) `$b == false` равно `0 == false` (`$b` это ноль а ноль является ложью) `false == false = true`

3) И наконец  `$a == $b` равно `'abc' == 0` (у нуля приоритет больше поскольку он число, и строка абс приводится к числу, но поскольку ему нет числового соответсвия то приводится к нулю) `0 == 0 = true`

и получается

```
$res = (true && true && true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 'что угодно';
$b = 0;
var_dump($a==true && $b==false && $a==$b); //true
```

Ссылка на документацию про операторы сравнения: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php

Вкратце - так происходит потому что работает приведение типов, поменяйте на тождественное равенство === и все изменится.

Comment: $a = 'что угодно'; ? передайте пожалуйста $а ='0';

Comment: Да, вы совершенно правы.